# How I can execute C# code using Roslyn in ASP.Net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, roslyn

I have peice of code in ASP.Net for execute code of C# using roslyn compiler. However, I use ASP.Net web forms to build user interface for execute the code. So,I want to take code from one textbox and by "Compile" button I show the result in another textbox.

So, I have this controls:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>Compiler Tool</h1>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                You can compile your source code of C# using Roslyn Compiler from Microsoft</p>
            <br/>

            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="185px"  Width="480px" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            </p>
            <p>

                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button_Click" Text="Compile" ForeColor="Black" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="138px" Width="390px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    </asp:Content>
```

And here the Handler event for it using C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Roslyn.Scripting;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;


namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var engine = new ScriptEngine();
            var session = engine.CreateSession();
            String code = TextBox3.Text;
            session.Execute(code);

        }

        protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How could I show the result of execution of Code (TextBox3) in TextBox2??

Iam beginner in ASP.Net environment, Any help??

Comment: Actually, I need to build that simple tool to support my research to show it as a prototype in the web application. I was done it as console application and it works but now I have to build user interface which accept the code from user and present the result in simple way.
So, If you know the way of doing that please, guide me.

Comment: What is the code behind the execute API of the Roslyn???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not near a dev pc, so I can't test the code, but here's what comes to mind:

You're not using the result of `session.Execute(code);`, so if a user were to put in `3+3`, it would get executed, and the return value would be 6, but since it's not captured, it simply would go out of scope.  If instead, you did `object result = session.Execute(code);`, the output would be the integer 6;  You could then call .ToString() on `result` and put that in your text box.

And of course be careful allowing users to execute arbitrary code on your webserver...

Comment: Thanx Rob, That what was missing here. However, it works with calculation of numbers but when I try simple code of C# like "Console.WriteLine("Hello World");" it throw NullReference Exception Error. Is the issue here regarding the Roslyn API which is execute??!

Comment: I feel that the problem from the Roslyn structure because it works as a tree of different API.

Comment: Console.WriteTine doesn't return anything, so that would be your null reference exception.  To capture that, you could try setting Console.Out to be a TextWriter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx